# How to linkWithCredential after you delete current user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

In my app, I'm trying following the documentation for how to [link multiple auths in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking), but when I follow the example for linking to a pre-existing account **linkWithCredential** fails with an error of **No user currently signed in.**

```js
// Get reference to the currently signed-in user
    let prevUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    // Sign in user with another account
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(_credential).then((user) => {
      let currentUser = user.user;
      // Merge prevUser and currentUser data stored in Firebase.
      // Note: How you handle this is specific to your application

      // After data is migrated delete the duplicate user
      return currentUser.delete().then(() => {
        // Link the OAuth Credential to original account
        console.log("!!DELETE FACEBOOK")
        return prevUser.linkWithCredential(_credential).then(() => {
          console.log("!!LINKING-FACEBOOK")
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("!!LINKING ERROR", error)
        });
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("!!SIGNIN-LINKED")
        // Sign in with the newly linked credential
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(_credential)
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Sign In Error", error);
    });
```

What I'm confused about is how can I can re-sign in to my previous account in order to be able to link the newly deleted account credentials to it?

Comment: Same exact error. Did you manage to solve it? :)

Comment: Ended up having to delete the user first, then logging in as the user I wanted to link to. So basically:

- Sign In with User you want to merge to
- Assign the credential from that login
- Delete that user
- Sign In with account you want to keep
- Link with Credential of the account you deleted
- Link

Comment: Thanks. I managed to come to the same conclusion! :)